# C++ Insert pointer into an array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

In need of some help in regards to dynamic arrays in c++

What i have is a dynamic array of pointers ie

```
Node* nodes;
```

and a function which adds new nodes to this array.

```
void insertNode(Node* nodeT){
   nodes = new nodeT;
}
```

Now I'm might be completely wrong with my logic because i know that doing the following will work but i want to know if there is a nicer way without using STL

```
Node * nodes = new Node(arg);
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: `Node* nodes;` isn't an array of pointers, it can only be a dynamic array of `Node`s

Comment: Yes, i thought it was obvious that it was an array of pointers to nodes. @abyss.7

Comment: Your code snippets and your descriptions do not make sense. Just this appears to be true: >"Now I'm might be completely wrong with my logic" ;)

Answer (score 3):

In the following `nodes` just represents a pointer to one Node object.

```
Node * nodes = new Node(arg);
```

To get an array over several Nodes you must tell the compiler to generate an array:

```
Node * nodes = new Node[size]();
```

Then you can insert new Objects like this

```
node[0] = ...
node[1] = ...
```

Alternatively, when you can't determine the number of nodes in advance you could use `std::vector`.

Comment: Thanks chrizke, what if we don't know the size of the array ??

Comment: I'd say always use `std::vector` and never use `new`. (`std::array` may be more suitable sometimes though than vector if available)

Comment: Well, if you don't know the size see my last sentence "Alternatively, when you can't determine the number of nodes in advance you could use std::vector"

Answer (score 1):

depends what for you need your pointers. You can use:

1. pointer array

   - easy to reallocate
   - easy access (index)
2. object array

   - almost the same as 1. but:
   - need to be **really** care-full with object constructor/destructor to avoid memory leaks 
     and conflicts
   - slower reallocations and insert/delete
   - very fast access
   - linear layout in memory (can speed up many things)
3. chained list

   - easy and fast to add/insert/delete items
   - slow access (nead to go through the chain)
   - well known thing ... can google it any time with source code included

I personally prefer option 2.

- have a template List< class T > which is the same as { T *dat; int num,siz; }
- dat is linear array of objects
- num is actual count of used objects
- siz is actual allocated array size
- add (T a) to end:  dat[num]=a; num++;
- insert (T a) to (int ix): for (i=num;i>ix;i--) dat[i]=dat[i-1]; dat[ix]=a; num++;
- delete (int ix): for (i=ix;i < num;i++) dat[i]=dat[i+1]; num--;
- reallocate up: siz<<=1; T *tmp=new T[siz]; for (i=0;i

  reallocate down: siz>>=1; T *tmp=new T[siz]; for (i=0;i

  dont forget to add range checking

  when num reach siz or siz/2 reallocate siz to double or half size (or what ever bigger than num can add hysteresis)

  dont forget do use **delete[] dat;** instead of **delete dat;** !!!

  T a; need to have implemented a(),~a() and a*=a; or a&=a;

  when properly implemented [] operator then can use also as multidimensional array

  release memory on List destructor

  add allocate function to speed up List usage (avoid relocations when aprox. size is known)

Option 1 is very similar to option 2, but instead of (T *dat) is (T **dat)

- need to extra new/delete every single item
- addressing trough two pointers item ix = *dat[ix] or dat[ix][0]
- insert/delete/relocate fors copying only pointers not objects (very fast)

P.S. I know most of you will use std instead (so please do not judge) but i am using this for almost two decades and also in platforms where is no std present. Known functionality/behaviour has proven a good thing for me on time and safety critical applications many times over.

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use `std::vector` instead of traditional array:

1. `std::vector` is safe array.
2. It's member of STL.
3. You can easily iterate it with lambda function and another.
4. your code will not have any garbage memory.
5. and so on.

Please visit:

[vector ref](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html)

Comment: Just a little detail: `std::vector` is not a member of the STL, it is a member of the C++ standard library. `vector` *is* a member of the STL, but this is irrelevant unless you are actually using the STL. There's a pretty good reference for [`std::vector` here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).